# AngularJS html5Mode in IE9 stuck in refresh loop

Tags: angularjs, redirect, internet-explorer-9

Our application is having problems when using html5Mode in IE9. I have commented out all our code except the router to ensure it is nothing to do with our code. There are no errors in the console except a warning stating "Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 standards." We are using version 1.2.0 of AngularJS. It is working perfect in IE10+, Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Changing to html5Mode true fixes the refresh loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was our back end controller. It was using logic to redirect, basically removing the # that the Angular router was adding. Angular was then adding the # back hence the refresh loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added   to declare the html is in html5 ?

Comment: We have <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning of all our pages.